# Register Dependency Injection for generic class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

So here's my application structure:

- Aplication

  - Repositores
- Web

  - Services

I have repository code like this

```
public interface IRepository<T> { }

public class Repository <T> { }

public interface ITestRepository : IRepository<Model> { }

public class TestRepository : Repository<Model>, ITestRepository { }

public interface ITest2Repository : IRepository<Model2> { }

public class Test2Repository : Repository<Model2>, ITest2Repository { }
```

and i'm using this repository for my service in Web like this:

```
public class TestService : ITestService
{
     private readonly ITestRepository testRepository;
     private readonly ITest2Repository test2Repository;

     public TestService(ITestRepository testRepository, ITest2Repository test2Repository)
     {
         this.testRepository = testRepository;
         this.test2Repository = test2Repository;
     }
}
```

Right now, i'm registering the repository in `Startup.cs` like this.

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<Model>), typeof(TestRepository));
services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<Model2>), typeof(Test2Repository));
services.AddScoped<ITestRepository, TestRepository>();
services.AddScoped<ITest2Repository, Test2Repository>();
```

and i want to simplified that. I recently googled the way to register generic class but it break my `Program.cs`

here's the error:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot instantiate implementation type 'Application.Repositories.Repository1[TEntity]' for service type 'Application.Repositories.Interfaces.IRepository1[TEntity]'.'

and here's how i register the repository:

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
services.AddScoped<ITestRepository, TestRepository>();
services.AddScoped<ITest2Repository, Test2Repository>();
```

TL;DR, any solution to simplified my registration for that repository?

Comment: How do the constructors of your `TestRepository` look like?

Comment: It looks like `Repository<T>` doesn't actually implement `IRepository<T>` - I can see why the DI system isn't happy about that.

Comment: @haim770 like this:
`public TestRepository(ApplicationContext context) : base (context) { }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add your own extension method to simplify the registration:

```
static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static void AddRepository<TInterface, TRepository, TModel>(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection) 
        where TInterface : IRepository<TModel> 
        where TRepository : TInterface
    {
        services.AddScoped<TInterface, TRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IRepository<TModel>, TRepository>();
    }
}

// usage:
services.AddRepository<ITestRepository, TestRepository, Model>();
```

For the error you mentioned, see Kirk's comment:

> It looks like `Repository<T>` doesn't actually implement `IRepository<T>` - I can see why the DI system isn't happy about that.